# extract data between two expression in unix shell script

Tags: grep

i have a set of tags, from which i need to extract some data. I knwo this might be simple. I am not able to get to the part exactly. The tag is shown bewlow.

```
<Response><Result>Success</Result></Response>
```

I want to extract whatever comes between the  tags. In this case, 'Success'.
I tried using the grep command , but couldnt get it done. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo "<Response><Result>Success</Result></Response>" | perl -npe 's/.*>([^<]+)<.*/$1/'
```

If the data is saved in a file:

```
perl -npe 's/.*>([^<]+)<.*/$1/' infile
```

Comment: I didnt get your command properly. I tried it, it is giving me the below error:bash: <Response><Result>Success</Result></Response>: No such file or directory

Comment: You don't use `bash`, use `perl` instead. Just type the command on terminal.

Comment: My need is to put the command in a shell script and when i run the script, i should get the output. Is there any workaround ? I use to extract strings which are too complex, but not able to do this simple one . Is there any way using grep ?

Comment: I can't think of a way to do what you want using `grep`. `grep` does not support `capture`, so *most of the time* you cannot extract *exactly* something from the text. I think you should use `sed` or `perl`.

Comment: Ok, using your command it worked ! I poked around grep a little bit, as you said , my requirement may not be possible using grep. Thanks anyway !